# Selenium tests with WebDriver and Visual Studio Online

Tags: selenium-webdriver, tfsbuild, azure-devops, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'd like to run a number of Selenium tests as a part of my product's Contionous Integration mechanism.  We're using Visual Studio Online.

I've tried using IE WebDriver and it could not connect to my resources.  I've tried deploying portable versio of Firefox and tests appear to be stuck - I'm guessing that there is a firewall prompt happening?

I've tried PhantomJs web driver, but that does not appear to properly render the test page at all (unless I'm doing something completely wrong)...

so... is it even possible to run Selenium based browser tests from Visual Studio Online build servers?

Comment: Are they running in the local machines? Also are the drivers are enabled as part of deployment?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is currently not supported by the hosted build controller. The way to do it is to set up a remote build controller and connect it with your visualstudio.com account. I haven't tried this out yet but here's instructions on how to do it with an Azure machine: http://erictummers.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/run-selenium-from-visualstudio-com/

Comment: Has this changed with the new build system? https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/overview